# Keeper of the shrines

Tags: riddle, rhyme

A small one I'd like to share from our upcoming puzzle game. Not that hard for the experienced.

> The angry can not find me, yet the proud go to my door.

> My tail eludes me when through the wind I soar.

> My shrines are east and west, my drums alert my master.

> But give me a dollar value, and you'll lose me even faster.

Comment: "But give me a dollar value, and you'll loose me even faster." Should that be lose rather than loose?

Comment: Is the spelling in the last line intentional -- `loose`?  Or should it be `lose`?

Comment: Last line was me derping. Its fixed now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone will need to edit this to prevent spoilers...

I think it is

> Head

> Angry people "lose their head," while proud people let things "go to their head."

> When an arrow flies, the head and tail do not meet.

> The shrines are your temples, and the eardrums in the head alert the head's master.

> With a price on their head, people tend to go into hiding.

Comment: OK, I edited it to prevent spoilers. For future reference, what you do is to put ">!" at the start of any paragraph you want hidden. (You have to do slightly funny things if you want to consecutive hidden paragraphs.)

Comment: Correct :) The head and tails thing is a double whammy, because its also the parts of a coin-toss outcome.

Answer (score 1):

*"The angry can not find me, yet the proud goes to my door."*

> Angry people tend not to listen reasoning but when they're proud of something they have achieved they want to hear praises.

*"My tail eludes me, when through the wind I soar."*

> Probably a reference to The Doppler Effect, eh?

*"My shrines are east and west, my drums alert my master."*

> Shrines and the cardinal points refer to ears on the sides of one's head. Ear**drums** transmit the sound to the inner ear eventually the brain gets alerted.

*"But give me a dollar value, and you'll lose me even faster."*

> One dollar is not much. If you do not value your hearing high enough and protect your ears during loud activities then you will definitely lose it.

**Thus I believe the riddle pertains to:**

> hearing.